# Implementing a Flexible Observer-Based Event System with Generic Container Support in C++

Tags: c++, c++14

I am working on an observer-based event system in C++14, where the system should be flexible enough to use different types of containers (like vector, map, etc.) for managing observers. The system currently consists of an Observer class for the observers, a Subject class to attach/detach observers, and an EventSystem class that inherits from Subject. My aim is to allow EventSystem to use a container type of my choice (e.g., VectorContainer, MapContainer) for managing observers.

Here's the problem: I want to generalize the container type in EventSystem so that it can work with both single-type containers (like VectorContainer) and pair-type containers (like MapContainer<Key, Value>). However, I am struggling with designing a container interface (IContainer) that can handle both single items and key-value pairs.

My existing code structure is as follows:

```
#include <functional>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename MessageType>
class Observer
{
public:
    virtual ~Observer() = default;
    
    void Handle(const MessageType& message) { ApplyHandle(message); }
private:

    virtual void ApplyHandle(const MessageType& message) = 0;
};

template<typename MessageType, typename ObserverType, typename observerId>
class Subject 
{
public:
    virtual ~Subject() = default;
    virtual void Attach(ObserverType& observer, const observerId& observerID) = 0;
    virtual void Detach(const observerId& observerID) = 0;
};

template<typename MessageType, typename ObserverType, typename observerId, typename ContainerType>
class EventSystem : public Subject<MessageType, ObserverType, observerId>
{
    public:

    ~EventSystem() = default;
    
    
    void Attach(const observerId& observerID, ObserverType& observer) override
    {
        mContainer.Add(observerID, observer);
    }
    
    void Detach(const observerId& observerID) override
    {
        mContainer.Remove(observerID);
    }
    
    private:
    ContainerType mContainer;
};

template <typename T>
class IContainer
{
public:
    virtual void Add(const T& item) = 0;     // Adds item
    virtual void Remove(const T& item) = 0;  // Remove the item if it exists in the container
    virtual ~IContainer() = default;
};

template <typename T, typename ContainerType>
class Container : public IContainer<T>
{
public:
    void Add(const T& item) override
    {
        container.Add(item);
    }

    void Remove(const T& item) override
    {
        container.Remove(item);
    }

private:
    ContainerType container;
};

template <typename T>
class VectorContainer
{
public:
    void Add(const T& item)
    {
        vect.push_back(item);
    }

    void Remove(const T& item)
    {
        // Assuming T has a valid equality comparison
        auto it = std::remove(vect.begin(), vect.end(), item);
        vect.erase(it, vect.end());
    }

private:
    std::vector<T> vect;
};

template <typename Key, typename Value>
class MapContainer
{
public:
    void Add(const std::pair<const Key, Value>& keyValue)
    {
        container.insert(keyValue);
    }

    void Add(const Key& key, const Value& value) 
    {
        container[key] = value;
    }

    void Remove(const std::pair<const Key, Value>& keyValue)
    {
        container.erase(keyValue.first);
    }

private:
    std::map<Key, Value> container;
};
```

The challenge is adapting the IContainer and Container classes to work with both T and std::pair<Key, Value>. The current implementation is limited to a single template parameter, which works well for VectorContainer but not for MapContainer<Key, Value>.

How can I modify the IContainer and Container classes, or my overall design, to accommodate both single-type and pair-type containers in an efficient and effective way?

This revised question specifically targets the need for a multi-parameter Add method and asks for design advice to implement it effectively in your container interface.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal working example, including a main function, where you demonstrate how the code works for vectors and what you expect it to do? I can't tell from your code. For example, the `EventSystem` calls `mContainer.Add` with two arguments. This would not work if the container type is a `VectorContainer`.

Comment: Study **Qt signal/slot** mechanism first, and **boost.signals2** next. If that didn't work, come back to see how to reinvent the wheel without using the `virtual` keyword.